# How to understand if one is eligible for research?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, career-development

What are the eligibility criteria for one to undergo research in Mathematics?

Or should I place the question as what virtues of a student are given importance when one is interviewed for a PhD programme in some reputable institute?

Or may be how will a student know himself whether he is eligible for research?

As I am interested in research, I wonder what are the conditions one should keep in mind while preparing for an interview/an exam for undergoing the same.

The fact is there is no specific syllabus  in this case which makes life more difficult.There is no one to guide you here on what will be the questions or how to answer them nor any books available

I know there are many in this site who are doing research or have successfully completed it.

Can I get some help from them?

Comment: Eligible for research? You don't apply to the *committee of mathematics* for permission to do research. Your PhD-interview question is more sensible. The best characteristic a prospective PhD student can have is prior research experience, of course. :-) It's worthwhile to do some mathematical research (it can be modest, non-ground-breaking research) before applying. It's pretty standard for first-year PhD students to know real analysis and algebra thoroughly; after that your expected knowledge depends on your prospective specialization.

Comment: I imagine you are now, or you once were, an undergarduate who has taken a few math courses. The people who taugfht you in those courses are the ones in the best position to help you with your questions. Go see them.

Comment: For the book recommendation part about preparing for an interview/exam for PhD candidacy: [this book seems a propos](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/recreational-mathematics/all-mathematics-you-missed-need-know-graduate-school)

Comment: thanks for all  your comments

Comment: I will definitely try your book @WillieWong

Comment: the book is really very good @WillieWong